# Returning exceptions from generics

Tags: java, spring, generics, exception

I currently have multiple classes, i.e. `FacadeA`...`FacadeZ`, which extend `FacadeBase`. `FacadeBase` should have (some sort of generic method?), i.e. `checkFacade`, which throws an exception `FacadeAException`...`FacadeZException` which extends `FacadeException`.

That's currently as far as I got. I'm stuck with the generic part (or whatever would solve my problem).

And yes, I know I can't instantiate generics like written in my example.

```
public abstract class FacadeBase {
  public void checkFacade(final String facadeId) throws Facade<A...Z>Exception {
    if (!isFacadeAvailable(facadeId)) {
      throw new Facade<A...Z>Exception(facadeId);
    }
  }
  ...
}

public class FacadeA extends FacadeBase {
  public void doSomethingWithFacadeA(final String facadeId) throws FacadeAException {
    checkFacade(facadeId));
    ...
  }
}

public class FacadeAException extends FacadeException {
  private FacadeAException(final String message) {
    super(message);
  }
}

public abstract class FacadeException extends Exception {
  private FacadeException(final String message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Since all the `Facade[A-Z]Exception`s extend `FacadeException`, the superclass method can and probably should declare (just) `FacadeException`.  At their discretion, the subclasses' methods can narrow that to specific `FacadeException` subclasses, though it's not immediately clear what is to be gained by doing so, or by having all those additional exceptions at all.

Comment: I have other methods which call multiple facades and want to distinguish the Exception, so I can/could handle them differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use generics but it will not be enough because you need to instantiate the specific type at runtime.
Broadly you have two ways :

- reflection way
- declarative way

1) The reflection way is not simple. Java doesn't provide all what you need to do that. You could inspire from or use library as Spring to do that.
The [`org.springframework.core.GenericTypeResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/GenericTypeResolver.html) should especially help you.
You could use the [`static Class<?> resolveTypeArgument(Class<?> clazz, Class<?> genericIfc)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/GenericTypeResolver.html#resolveTypeArgument-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class-)  method that :

> Resolve the single type argument of the given generic interface
>   against the given target class which is assumed to implement the
>   generic interface and possibly declare a concrete type for its type
>   variable.

such as :

```
public abstract class FacadeBase<T extends FacadeException> {

    private final Class<T> genericClazz;
    public FacadeBase () {
        this.genericClazz = (Class<T>) GenericTypeResolver.resolveTypeArgument(getClass(), FacadeBase.class);    
    }
}
```

Now you get a way to instantiate the class of the generic with `genericClazz.newInstance()` or better `Constructor.newInstance()`.

2) The declarative way is simpler but requires some boiler plate code.

Make your abstract class a generic class that specifies the exception type and provide a constructor that stores the exception to throw.
For example :

```
public abstract class FacadeBase<T extends FacadeException> {

    private Supplier<T> suppException;

    public FacadeBase(Supplier<T> suppException) {
        this.suppException = suppException;
    }

    public void checkFacadeAvailability(final String facadeId) throws T {
        if (!isFacadeAvailable(facadeId)) {
            throw suppException.get();
        }
    }
}
```

Subclasses should so call the super constructor with their supplier :

```
public class FacadeA extends FacadeBase<FacadeExceptionA>{

    public FacadeA(Supplier<FacadeExceptionA> suppException) {
        super(suppException);
    }   
}
```

As alternative you could replace the `Supplier` by a `Class` parameter but the overall idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks. Btw. im using `Spring` (just updated the tags). Could you kindly also point out the `Spring`-way if its more elegant. These facades are `@Components` (if it matters).

Comment: @user871611 You are welcome. Sure. I added the information and updated with an example. Not tested but it should not be very far.

Answer (score 1):

There are two good reasons for stopping at `throws FacadeException`:

- The contract of `FacadeBase.checkFacade` would anyway force clients to catch `FacadeException` (assuming the good practice of programming to interface)
- Exception classes cannot be generic. Although you can use an `Exception` type parameter in the `throws` clause, this is simply over-engineering (in addition to going against best practices)

So subclasses should declare `throws  Facade<A...Z>Exception` or omit this clause completely where applicable. But this doesn't make a difference to the client/caller (unless they take the discouraged route of declaring subclass types)

If you need to check ***which*** exception was raised on the caller side, then you would anyway have to know the concrete exception class, because you cannot check `instanceof  T` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the heart of the problem is how to declare and implement a `checkFacade()` method along the lines represented schematically by this pseudocode:

> ```
> public abstract class FacadeBase {
>   public void checkFacade(final String facadeId) throws Facade<A...Z>Exception {
>     if (!isFacadeAvailable(facadeId)) {
>       throw new Facade<A...Z>Exception(facadeId);
>     }
>   }
>   ...
> }
> ```

I note first that associating *characteristic* exceptions with the concrete `FacadeBase` subclasses breaks abstraction.  The subclasses may certainly throw their own specific exceptions, but as soon as other classes know or care about those specifically, especially so as to be able to recognize those subclasses, the abstraction falls apart.

In particular, if your `isFacadeAvailable(facadeId)` method has anything to do with subclasses of `FacadeBase` being available in the Java classpath, then that seems likely to be correlated with that facade implementation's characteristic exception being available.  In that case, you could not expect to be able to instantiate a `FacadeQException` when `FacadeQ` is unavailable, and you would likely run into class loading failures when any of the exceptions were not present in the classpath.

In the second place, I observe that because all the `Facade[A-Z]Exception`s extend `FacadeException`, `FacadeBase.checkFacade()` can simply declare `FacadeException` instead of declaring all the individual exceptions.  That will not prevent other code from catching the specific exceptions, if indeed those are still thrown by this method.

In order to actually throw the individual exceptions, you would need to build them first, and that calls for either a big `switch` block, a big `if`/`then`/`else` statement, a factory method, or reflective instantiation of the appropriate exception class, or some combination of those.  Note well that exceptions are objects; they can be assigned to variables and returned from methods.  A `throw` statement can throw *any* `Throwable`; it does not need to be a newly instantiated one.  Thus, you could consider something along these lines:

```
public void checkFacade(final String facadeId) throws FacadeException {
    if (!isFacadeAvailable(facadeId)) {
        throw createFacadeException(facadeId);
    }
}

private FacadeException createFacadeException(String facadeId) {
    if ("A".equals(facadeId)) {
        return new FacadeAException();
    } else // ...
}
```

**HOWEVER**, I urge you to instead consider giving `FacadeException` a member by which to convey the *ID* of the unavailable facade, instead of doing that by throwing a facade-specific exception.  Or if you don't want to put that on `FacadeException` itself, then define a `FacadeUnavailableException` subclass that carries it:

```
public class FacadeUnavailableException extends FacadeException {
    private final String facadeId;

    private FacadeAException(String message, String facadeId) {
        super(message);
        this.facadeId = facadeId;
    }

    public String getFacadeId() {
        return facadeId;
    }
}
```

With that, your problem gets much simpler:

```
public void checkFacade(final String facadeId) throws FacadeUnavailableException {
    if (!isFacadeAvailable(facadeId)) {
        throw new FacadeUnavailableException("unavailable", facadeId);
    }
}
```